# Minecraft testfor XP Gained?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a new map on Minecraft and I was wondering if anyone knew how to testfor XP gain. For example if I gained 10 levels it would output a signal, and if I gain another 10 levels, it would output another signal. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector `l, lm` to test for experience levels. `l` means maximum  experience level, `lm` means minimum.

To test for a player with at least 10 levels of experience:

```
/testfor @a[lm=10]
```

If you only want the `testfor` to succeed once for each player, add a tag to the player:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[lm=10] add xp10
```

And change the command to:

```
/testfor @a[lm=10,tag=!xp10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need scoreboard, the level criteria.
Record the previous level, compare it with the current level. If a-b is larger or equal to 10, then output signal, and set the score to the current level.